# Extract first word of string in bash using regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash

I have a string like "abc def". Using Bash and regular expressions I want to set a Bash variable to the value of the first word. I have tried the following code:

```
testVar="abc def"
re="^[[:space]]([a-zA-z0-9)[[[:space]]|$]"
sub=[[ "$testVar" ~= ${re} ]]; ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
echo "${sub}"
```

This gives me the response "./test1.sh: line 3: abc def: command not found". Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Extracting first word doesn't need regex and your regex is also wrong, any reason you're looking for a regex solution?

Comment: It is the only way I could find without using external commands.

Comment: There are too many problems with the regular expression to list all of them.  `:space` should be `:space:`.   `[a-zA-z0-9` should be `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.  `[[[` should be `[[`.  ... .  Try building regular expressions up slowly and testing as you go along.  There are several online tools to help explain and debug regular expressions.

Comment: The effect of `sub=[[ "$testVar" ~= ${re} ]]` is to run the command `"$testVar" ~= ${re} ]]` (i.e. run whatever `"$testVar"` expands to with arguments: `~=`, whatever `${re}` expands to, and `]]`) with the environment variable `sub` set to the value `[[`.  See [Is it shell portable to run a command on the same line after variable assignment?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97302/264812).  Note also that the regular expression matching operator inside `[[ ... ]]` is `=~`, not `~=`.

Comment: Always use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to check your shell code for problems.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution using `read`:

```
testVar="abc def"
read word _ <<< "$testVar"
echo "$word"
```

```
abc
```

If you really want to use a regex then use:

```
re='[^[:blank:]]+'
[[ $testVar =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
```

```
abc
```

Here `[^[:blank:]]+` matches 1 or more of any non-whitespace characters.

Comment: I find a few problems with this approach:
1. There normally is no leading whitespace.
2. :space: allows me to include leading newlines in the group to be discarded.
3. I want to assign the result to a Bash variable. Echo was only used for testing.

Comment: For regex solution use: `[[ $testVar =~ [^[:space:]]+ ]] && var="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"` This will work whether leading spaces are there or not.

Comment: The solution with `read` can be modified to handle strings that have newlines before the first word: `read -r -d '' word _ <<< "$testVar"`.  The `-r` option should almost always be used with `read` to avoid weird things happening if the input contains backslashes.  The `-d ''` causes `read` to read the entire input, even if it contains newlines (or any character other than ASCII zero (NUL)).

Answer (score 2):

Another:

```
$ echo ${testVar%% *}
abc
```

More here: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Answer (score 1):

If your string isn't space delimited. You can use sed to split the string into a new line for each delimiter, and use head to select only the first row.

```
$ testVar="abc,def,ghi"
$ echo $testVar | sed 's/,/\n/g' | head -n 1
abc
```